# Login windows forms c#

Tags: c#, database, authentication

I have employees SQL DB and in the DB I have user table that contain Sid and password.

I want to verify the enter details is correct and if it the user can enter to the system.

Here is my start code for the verifying and it's not working:

```
public void confirm(string name, string pass)
{
    string connection_sting = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Senan\Documents\employees.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
    using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connection_sting)) 
    {
        cnn.Open();

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from employees where name=@Sid and pass=@password" , cnn))
        {
            SqlDataReader reader;
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.HasRows)
                MessageBox.Show("pass");
            else
                MessageBox.Show("fail");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where did you pass the command parameters?

Comment: Do not store and pass passwords as plain text. Use passwords' hashes instead.

Comment: You have to set the parameters of the SqlCommand. I hope you don't mix the layers in actual application like you did in your sample code here. Otherwise is bad start.

Comment: You're using integrated security and plain text passwords. May as well not bother with a logon process as it should be easily hackable. Your users could just look in the database for the passwords.

Comment: what you mean on mix layers?

Comment: Lee Willis thanks from the advise.. can you tell how to avoid that?

Comment: At the very least do what @Dmitry Bychenko mentions and use password hashes instead. The plain text password is never stored anywhere then.

Comment: @B0Andrew means that you are mixing UI, business logic and data access into one layer (ie in one method). This makes your application difficult to scale and code re-use is harder.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the parameters

```
 public void confirm(string name, string pass)
    {
        string connection_sting = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Senan\Documents\employees.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
        using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connection_sting)) 
        {
            cnn.Open();

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from employees where name=@Sid and pass=@password" , cnn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sid", name);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", pass);
                SqlDataReader reader;
                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (reader.HasRows)
                    MessageBox.Show("pass");
                else
                    MessageBox.Show("fail");
            }
        }
  }
```

Comment: I get this error:-  Invalid object name 'employees'

Comment: @SenanZedan: Just check the table name is correct

Comment: I get this error Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'user'. when I the execute reader command run. the table name is called user.

Comment: User is a reserved word in SQL. Wrap it in square brackets [user]

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your data access code in while loop like this: `while(reader.read()){..}`. If you don't need to loop, then you still need to call `read()` method. E.g. `reader.read();` You need to call this method before you call hasRows. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass parameters to the command object like this

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sid", name);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", pass);
```

Add above code before this

```
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```